# why is the inner loop of the question only working the first time it runs -- algo questions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

The have a solution to a problem that looks like this. The input for instances is meant to me an integer and an array. Given the following input

```js
console.log(finalInstances(13, [40, 89, 79, 76, 66, 60, 8, 90, 19, 39, 53, 30, 93]))

function finalInstances(instances, averageUtil) {
  // Write your code here
  for (var i = 0; i < averageUtil.length; i++) {
    if (averageUtil[i] < 25) {
      if (instances > 1) {
        i += 9
        console.log(i)
        instances = Math.ceil((instances / 2));
      }
    } else if (averageUtil[i] > 60) {
      if (instances * 2 < (2 * 10 ^ 8)) {
        instances = instances * 2;
        i = i + 9;
      }
    }
  }
  return instances
}
```

The output for this particular test case should be 52. However, I always get 26 (half of 52). After debugging my solution, I realize that the second IF statement in my solution doesn't work as intended. It only perform instances = instances * 2 the first time we enter the statement, but no longer after (hence why my return is 26 and not 52). Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here or how I should alter my code?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why should the output be 52? What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: `10 ^ 8` doesn't do what you think it does. `^` is XOR, not exponentiation.

Comment: You can use scientific notation: `2e8`

Comment: sorry I didn't post the question because it is lengthy. pretty much meant to divide the integer instances in half when the number in the array is less than 25, and double the integer instances when the number in the array is greater than 60. When either of these actions are performed I need to skip 10 spots (or indices). Numbers in between are negligible

Comment: @Barmar thanks !!! that definitely solved that issue

Comment: Solved *that* issue, or solved *the* issue?

Comment: @jarmod I think I haven't covered some edge cases in my solution because some test cases aren't running still but yes he had the right idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is supposed to do, but I suspect

```
if (instances * 2 < (2 * 10 ^ 8))
```

is not doing what you want. `^` is bitwise XOR and has lower precedence than `*`, so `(2 * 10 ^ 8)` is `20 XOR 8` which is `28`.

Use `2e8` to get `2` with 8 zeroes after it.

```js
console.log(finalInstances(13, [40, 89, 79, 76, 66, 60, 8, 90, 19, 39, 53, 30, 93]))

function finalInstances(instances, averageUtil) {
  // Write your code here
  for (var i = 0; i < averageUtil.length; i++) {
    if (averageUtil[i] < 25) {
      if (instances > 1) {
        i += 9
        console.log(i)
        instances = Math.ceil((instances / 2));
      }
    } else if (averageUtil[i] > 60) {
      if (instances * 2 < 2e8) {
        instances = instances * 2;
        i = i + 9;
      }
    }
  }
  return instances
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On line 6 you are increasing the index variable by 9. That means that you are skipping over all of the elements of the array that are greater than 60.

Comment: it is meant to do that. there is an element at the end of the array that is greater than 60 and not skipped. instances is supposed to double there but it doesnt